# Apply different aggregations to groups of pandas GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like

```
     A     B    C   D
one  2  10.0    0  11
two  5   NaN  NaN   8
```

and did a groupby with

```
df.groupby(np.array(['min', 'max', 'min', 'max']), axis=1)
```

Now I want to aggregate the groups with different functions. The 'min' group shall be aggregated with `.sum(axis=1)` while the 'max' group shall be aggregated with `.sum(axis=1, skipna=False)`.
The desired output would be

```
     min  max
one    2   21
two    5  NaN
```

Is there any built-in way to do this?

Comment: Is `df.groupby(['min', 'max', 'min', 'max'], axis=1)` correct?

Comment: It works for me, but I'll clarify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need custom function, because it is not `built-in`:

```
def f(x):
    if x.name == 'min':
        return x.sum(axis=1)
    elif x.name == 'max':
        return x.sum(axis=1, skipna=False)

df = df.groupby(['min', 'max', 'min', 'max'], axis=1).apply(f)
print (df)
      max  min
one  21.0  2.0
two   NaN  5.0
```